# Convert vector into 2-column dataframe with string-subsetting in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I don't think I'll be able to find a similar version of this question posted because I feel it's a relatively unique problem, however please point me in the correct direction if I am mistaken. I am working with the following vector that I need converted into a dataframe:

```
myvec = structure(c(1.03, 2.3, -1.2, -0.09, -0.31, -0.51, 3.4, 3, 0.07, 
0.02, 1.05, -0.02, 2.03), .Names = c("Intercept", "DEF-1017", 
"DEF-1025", "DEF-103", "DEF-1043", "DEF-1046", "DEF-1048", "DEF-1076", 
"OFF-1017", "OFF-1025", "OFF-103", "OFF-1046", "OFF-1076"))

head(myvec)
Intercept  DEF-1017  DEF-1025   DEF-103  DEF-1043  DEF-1046 
 1.03      2.30     -1.20     -0.09     -0.31     -0.51
```

This vector is supposed to have offensive (OFF) and defensive (DEF) coefficients for 7 different users (users 1017, 1025, 103, 1043, 1046, 1048, 1076), however there are offensive coefficients missing for two users. I need this converted into a dataframe with 4 columns (defense ID, offense ID, defense coefficient, offense coefficient). To be more specific, I'd like to get the following dataframe, accounting in this manner for missing values:

```
mydf = structure(list(DEFID = c("DEF-1017", "DEF-1025", "DEF-103", "DEF-1043", 
"DEF-1046", "DEF-1048", "DEF-1076"), OFFID = c("OFF-1017", "OFF-1025", 
"OFF-103", NA, "OFF-1046", NA, "OFF-1076"), DEFVAL = c(2.3, -1.2, 
-0.09, -0.31, -0.51, 3.4, 3), OFFVAL = c(0.07, 0.02, 1.05, NA, 
-0.02, NA, 2.03)), .Names = c("DEFID", "OFFID", "DEFVAL", "OFFVAL"
), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

mydf
     DEFID    OFFID DEFVAL OFFVAL
1 DEF-1017 OFF-1017   2.30   0.07
2 DEF-1025 OFF-1025  -1.20   0.02
3  DEF-103  OFF-103  -0.09   1.05
4 DEF-1043     <NA>  -0.31     NA
5 DEF-1046 OFF-1046  -0.51  -0.02
6 DEF-1048     <NA>   3.40     NA
7 DEF-1076 OFF-1076   3.00   2.03
```

The intercept value gets dropped / isn't included in the table, and everything else gets formatted as would be expected. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use the `tidyr` package for tasks like this:

first conver to a dataframe format:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame(names= names(myvec),
           values=myvec)
```

next filter out the intercept, and rearrange with `tidyr` commands:

```
df %>% filter(names !="Intercept") %>% 
  extract(names, into=c("coeff", "user"), "([[:alnum:]]+)-([[:alnum:]]+)") %>% 
  spread(coeff, values) 
# A tibble: 7 x 3
   user   DEF   OFF
* <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1  1017  2.30  0.07
2  1025 -1.20  0.02
3   103 -0.09  1.05
4  1043 -0.31    NA
5  1046 -0.51 -0.02
6  1048  3.40    NA
7  1076  3.00  2.03
```

If you want the names etc to be exactly as you listed above just process a little further:

```
df %>% filter(names !="Intercept") %>% 
  extract(names, into=c("coeff", "user"), "([[:alnum:]]+)-([[:alnum:]]+)") %>% 
  spread(coeff, values) %>% 
  mutate(DEFID = paste("DEF", user, sep="-"),
         OFFID = paste("OFF", user, sep="-")) %>%
  rename(DEFVAL=DEF,
         OFFVAL=OFF) %>% 
  select(DEFID, OFFID, DEFVAL, OFFVAL)
# A tibble: 7 x 4
     DEFID    OFFID DEFVAL OFFVAL
     <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 DEF-1017 OFF-1017   2.30   0.07
2 DEF-1025 OFF-1025  -1.20   0.02
3  DEF-103  OFF-103  -0.09   1.05
4 DEF-1043 OFF-1043  -0.31     NA
5 DEF-1046 OFF-1046  -0.51  -0.02
6 DEF-1048 OFF-1048   3.40     NA
7 DEF-1076 OFF-1076   3.00   2.03
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is exactly what you wanted. I used `split`, `substr`, and `merge`. And I think this is a shortest way to do it which gives your desired output.

```
 library(dplyr)
 DF <- tibble::rownames_to_column(data.frame(myvec))
 DF <- DF[DF$rowname!= "Intercept",]
 dff <- split(DF , f = substr(DF$rowname, 1, 3) )
 dff2 <- dff[[1]]; dff3 <- dff[[2]]
 dff2$ID <- substr(dff2$rowname, 5, nchar(dff2$rowname))
 dff3$ID <- substr(dff3$rowname, 5, nchar(dff3$rowname))
 DF2 <- merge(dff2,dff3,by="ID", all = TRUE)
 DF2 <- DF2[,c(2,4,3,5)]
 names(DF2) <- c("DEFID", "OFFID", "DEFVAL", "OFFVAL")

 DF2

    DEFID     OFFID    DEFVAL OFFVAL
 1 DEF-1017  OFF-1017   2.30   0.07
 2 DEF-1025  OFF-1025  -1.20   0.02
 3 DEF-103   OFF-103   -0.09   1.05
 4 DEF-1043      <NA>  -0.31     NA
 5 DEF-1046  OFF-1046  -0.51  -0.02
 6 DEF-1048      <NA>   3.40     NA
 7 DEF-1076  OFF-1076   3.00   2.03
```